# How to build an Excel file with login connexion

Tags: visual-studio-2008, excel, sharepoint-2010, ms-office, vba

I am looking for a way to build a kind of excel application based on an single excel file, used by different kind of users which different level of authorization.

In an ideal world, The user open the excel file and immediately a username and a password are asked. Then, when the user is connected, he only sees the information in the file corresponding to his level of authorization.

I know I can protect my excel file with a password, or protect a file with reading only but I really need a connexion with login.

I really don't know how to cross login connexion and an excel file, is it possible ?
Have you any ideas to help me begin ?

FYI : I can work with Visual Studio 2008, Excel 2010 and SharePoint 2010.

Regards,

Jay

Comment: It depends on how sensitive your data is.  If it is particularly sensitive then I would think about moving the actual data to an external database (or an encrypted file if you don't have access to one) and then just using Excel as an interface to that data.

Comment: All the data are already in several databases. The purpose of this excel file is more than information storing. In fact, there is data from different country, and I have users who can interact only with the data of their own country, and users who can interact with all the data. The users are used to excel so I have to keep excel for the interface of this "application", but I need to be sure that only the people with the rights authorization runs certain macro, modify data,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a UserForm to the workbook which, when called by the `Workbook_Open()` event, asks the user for their login credentials. Then use that data to show/hide the relevant data in the workbook.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a very good idea. But if I hide data to show only the relevant data, does a user can Show the hidden data with excel manipulation or I can protect that too ?